# Is there a way to reform this so that I get the INTERSECTION of checked layer groups?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap

I am doing a fairly complex thing for my newbie to Leaflet, JavaScript, and Stack Exchange brain. I am building a Leaflet map that displays parks by specific criteria. I am using the default Leaflet layer control, for which I have given a new HTML parent outside the map. I initially had a challenge where toggling on two layer groups and then toggling off one would remove the markers that existed in both layer groups. I solved this by creating dummy layer as seen in the first code example below.

That said, I want to change the logic so that my map only displays the logical intersection between layer groups. I attempted to refactor the data for my markers in the second example here but I am stuck for how to get this to function as I want.

I can't manage to find a good method that allows me to use the default layer control while only displaying markers that have all of specific attributes.

Here is the code I have now:

```
var ColorIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [50, 50],
        iconAnchor:   [22.5, 45],
        popupAnchor:  [5,  -30]
    }
});



var blueIcon = new ColorIcon({iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6235-3462-4436-a462-636533303161/PINBLUE.png'}),
    redIcon = new ColorIcon({iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3338-6635-4361-b964-366333643732/PINRED.png'}),
    greenIcon = new ColorIcon({iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6263-6236-4366-b934-646361386631/PINGREEN.png'}),
    yellowIcon = new ColorIcon({iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6530-6637-4866-b564-373036303930/PINYELLOW.png'}),
    brownIcon = new ColorIcon({iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3239-6138-4435-a331-636535323762/PINBROWN.png'});


var Lurparken = L.marker([59.3011142,17.9939973], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/lurparken'>Lurparken</a>"),
    Aspuddsparken    = L.marker([59.3075995,17.9944431], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/aspuddsparken'>Aspuddsparken</a>"),
    Sparvagnsparken    = L.marker([59.3298868,18.0031605], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken'>Spårvagnsparken</a>"),
    Fredhallsparkens    = L.marker([59.3320485,18.0029481], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm'>Fredhällsparkens Plaskdamm</a>"),
    Uggleparken    = L.marker([59.3343715,18.0040208], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksply.com/uggleparken'>Uggleparken</a>"),
    Observatorielundens    = L.marker([59.3413877,18.056007], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek'>Observatorielundens Parklek</a>"),
    Kronobergsparken    = L.marker([59.331715,18.0335563], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/parklekkronobergsparken'>Parklek Kronobergsparken</a>"),
    Drakenbergsparken    = L.marker([59.314187,18.038608], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/drakenbergsparken'>Drakenbergsparken</a>"),
    Fruktlekparken    = L.marker([59.3109872,18.0221863], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/fruktlekparken'>Fruktlekparken</a>"),
    Junotappan    = L.marker([59.3235004,18.0720134], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/junotappan'>Junotäppan</a>"),
    AndersFranzens    = L.marker([59.311421,18.104492], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/andersfranzenspark'>Anders Franzens Park</a>"),
    Kristinebergs    = L.marker([59.334675,18.0063813], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/kristinebergsekparken'>Kristinebergs Ekparken</a>"),
    Engelskaparkens    = L.marker([59.3377166,18.0012396], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/engelskaparkensplaskdamm'>Engelskaparkens Plaskdamm</a>"),
    Vasaparken    = L.marker([59.3399655,18.0419433], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/vasaparkenlekpark'>Vasaparken Lekpark</a>"),
    KungsholmsStrand    = L.marker([59.3358832,18.0406834], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/lekplatsenkungsholmsstrand'>Lekplatsen Kungsholms Strand</a>"),
    IvarLos    = L.marker([59.3204862,18.0609756], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/ivarlospark'>Ivar Los Park</a>"),
    Luxparken    = L.marker([59.324224,18.0092568], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/luxparken'>Luxparken</a>"),
    Ralis = L.marker([59.3377166,18.0012396], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/ralisparklek'>Rålis Parklek</a>"),
    Blomsterdalen    = L.marker([59.3078405,18.0261414], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/lekplatsblomsterdalen'>Lekplats Blomsterdalen</a>"),
    Aventyrsparken    = L.marker([59.304649,18.0355265], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Äventyrsparken i Årstabergsparken'),
    Sannadalsparken    = L.marker([59.3153587,18.0091349], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/sannadalsparken'>Sannadalsparken</a>"),
    Signalparken    = L.marker([59.3277189,18.0140405], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/signalparken'>Signalparken</a>"),
    Vangavan    = L.marker([59.3219577,17.9926997], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/vangavan'>Vängåvan</a>"),
    LillaBatparken    = L.marker([59.3191497,17.9831104], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/lillabatparken'>Lilla Båtparken</a>"),
    Arstabergsparken    = L.marker([59.3049749,18.0255049], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Årstabergsparken'),
    Angbybadet  = L.marker([59.3364975,17.8986038], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup('Ängbybadet'),
    Trekantsbadet   = L.marker([59.3126158,18.0106735], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup('Trekantsbadet'),
    Solviksbadet    = L.marker([59.3151737,17.9660969], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup('Solviksbadet'),
    Malarhojdsbadet = L.marker([59.3001388,17.9254848], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup('Mälarhöjdsbadet'),
    TantoSandBeach = L.marker([59.3118604,18.0384076], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup('Tanto sand beach'),
    SicklaStrandbad = L.marker([59.301995,18.1246048], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup('Sickla strandbad'),
    Reimersholmskajen = L.marker([59.3170847,18.023135], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Reimersholmskajen​ Lekpark'),
    GustafAdolfsParklek = L.marker([59.3370994,18.0997679], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Gustaf Adolfs Parklek'),
    Honungslekplatsen = L.marker([59.3454418,18.0925069], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Honungslekplatsen'),
    LekparkLinnegatan = L.marker([59.3356294,18.0876201], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Lekpark Linnegatan 74'),
    LekplatsBranneriet = L.marker([59.3174423,18.0171169], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Lekplats Bränneriet'),
    Hogalid = L.marker([59.3172023,18.0356642], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Högalid park'),
    Sockerskalen = L.marker([59.3092874,18.048598], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Sockerskålen lekpark'),
    Vitabergsparkens = L.marker([59.3105286,18.0899339], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Vitabergsparkens lekplats'),
    Pampasparken    = L.marker([59.3506851,18.0019008], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Pampasparken'),
    Bergsparken = L.marker([59.3532246,17.9985754], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Bergsparken'),
    LekplatsNybodagatan = L.marker([59.3561657,17.9906558], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Lekplats Nybodagatan'),
    Skytteholmsparken = L.marker([59.3588629,17.9929818], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Skytteholmsparken'),
    Blomparken = L.marker([59.2985831,18.0377624], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Blomparken'),
    Grynkvarnsparken = L.marker([59.2974055,18.0735674], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Grynkvarnsparken'),
    Sickla = L.marker([59.3048158,18.108975], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Sickla park'),
    Dalen = L.marker([59.3061503,18.1535634], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Dalén park'),
    Motalaparken = L.marker([59.3533865,18.0942552], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Motalaparken'),
    Dianaparkens = L.marker([59.3563711,18.1012935], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Dianaparkens Parklek'),
    Ekorrparken = L.marker([59.3559581,18.0852826], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Ekorrparken Lekplats'),
    Halsingehajden = L.marker([59.3440572,18.04076], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Lekplatsen Hälsingehöjden'),
    Solvandan = L.marker([59.343872,18.0337046], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Solvändan'),
    TranebergsbronSkatepark = L.marker([59.3049749,18.0255049], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Tranebergsbron Skatepark'),
    Solvikangens = L.marker([59.3166851,17.9613786], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/solvikangenslekplats'>Solvikangens Lekplats</a>"),
    SolvikSkatepark= L.marker([59.3166483,17.9618368], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Solvik skatepark Rhino'),
    Vattersdalden = L.marker([59.2964647,18.0595962], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/vattersdalden'>Vättersdälden</a>"),
    Trollparken = L.marker([59.3003486,18.0618205], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/trollparken'>Trollparken</a>"),
    HumlanSkatepark = L.marker([59.3399548,18.070861], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Humlan skateboard park'),
    SkateparkRhino = L.marker([59.3349077,17.9886289], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Skatepark Rhino'),
    StoraBlecktornsparken = L.marker([59.3069209,18.0866587], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/storablecktornsparken'>Stora Blecktornsparken</a>"),
    PrimusSkatepark = L.marker([59.3250964,17.9998018], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Primus Skatepark'),
    RalisSkatepark = L.marker([59.3290717,18.0217644], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Rålis Skatepark'),
    KristinebergsSkatepark = L.marker([59.3370164,18.0037855], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Kristinebergs Skatepark'),
    ParkblekenSkaneglantan = L.marker([59.3112462,18.0702012], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/parklekenskaneglantan'>Parkbleken Skånegläntan</a>"),
    Humlegarden = L.marker([59.3406553,18.0728746], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/humlegardenparklek'>Humlegården Parklek</a>"),
    Timmermansparken = L.marker([59.3130356,18.0624603], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/timmermansparken'>Timmermansparken</a>"),
    BjornsTradgard = L.marker([59.31533,18.0740494], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/bjornstradgard'>Björns Trädgård</a>"),
    BjornsSkatepark = L.marker([59.3151381,18.074384], {icon: redIcon}).bindPopup('Björns Skatepark'),
    Bryggartappan = L.marker([59.3102588,18.0797964], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/bryggartppan'>Bryggartäppan</a>"),
    EllenKeysLekplats = L.marker([59.3440353,18.0641552], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/ellenkeyslekplats'>Ellen Keys Lekplats</a>"),
    Pontonjarparkens= L.marker([59.329508,18.0325937], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Pontonjärparkens lekplats'),
    KungsholmsHamnplan = L.marker([59.3275721,18.0462158], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Lekplatsen Kungsholms hamnplan'),
    Byparkens = L.marker([59.3524237,17.9842882], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Byparkens Parklek'),
    TranebergsFritidspark = L.marker([59.3345913,17.9887147], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/tranebergsfritidspark'>Tranebergs Fritidspark</a>"),
    Tessinparken = L.marker([59.3446553,18.0953217], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Parklek Tessinparken'),
    VanadislundensNedre = L.marker([59.3472582,18.0534746], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/vanadislundensnedrelekplats'>Vanadislundens Nedre Lekplats</a>"),
    VanadislundensOvre = L.marker([59.3493288,18.0541187], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/vanadislundensovrelekplats'>Vanadislundens Övre Lekplats</a>"),
    Annedalsparken = L.marker([59.363506,17.9476855], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Annedalsparken'),
    KungsholmensInternationellaBiblioteket = L.marker([59.3049749,18.0255049], {icon: yellowIcon}).bindPopup('Kungsholmens Internationella biblioteket'),
    LillaKvarnholmen = L.marker([59.3153135,18.1378676], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Lilla Kvarnholmen Lekplats'),
    MulleMecks = L.marker([59.3818079,17.9901311], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Mulle Mecks Lekpark'),
    Simbaparken = L.marker([59.3049749,18.0255049], {icon: yellowIcon}).bindPopup('Simbaparken'),
    LekBusNacka = L.marker([59.3049749,18.0255049], {icon: yellowIcon}).bindPopup('Lek o Bus i Nacka'),
    MallScandinavia = L.marker([59.3691656,18.005247], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('Westfield Mall of Scandinavia'),
    Langsjoparken = L.marker([59.3049749,18.0255049], {icon: yellowIcon}).bindPopup('ÅrstaberLångsjöparkengsparken');


    var main = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1,
                zoomControl: false,
                accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWljaGFlbGNwIiwiYSI6ImNrN3V5eHVwNTAxMzgza2x1d2s1N3lkbmIifQ.Rmgw9tQHXVTL5_w6jvGjlw'
        });
    var baseMaps = {
        'OSM': main
    };
    var map = L.map('mapid', {
                 center: [59.3244941,18.028934],
                 zoom: 12,
                 layers: [main]
        });

    var overlay = [];    
      overlay[0] = [Sparvagnsparken, Fredhallsparkens, Uggleparken, Observatorielundens, Kronobergsparken, Drakenbergsparken, Fruktlekparken, Junotappan, AndersFranzens, Kristinebergs, Engelskaparkens, Vasaparken, KungsholmsStrand, Luxparken, IvarLos, Ralis, Blomsterdalen, Sannadalsparken, Signalparken, LillaBatparken, Vangavan, Lurparken, Humlegarden, StoraBlecktornsparken, Bryggartappan, VanadislundensOvre, VanadislundensNedre, EllenKeysLekplats, Timmermansparken, ParkblekenSkaneglantan, BjornsTradgard, TranebergsFritidspark, Trollparken, Aspuddsparken, Solvikangens, Vattersdalden];
      overlay[1] = [Sparvagnsparken, Fredhallsparkens, Uggleparken,Observatorielundens,Kronobergsparken,Drakenbergsparken,Fruktlekparken,Junotappan,Kristinebergs,Engelskaparkens,Vasaparken,Blomsterdalen,Vangavan,Lurparken,Humlegarden,StoraBlecktornsparken,Bryggartappan,VanadislundensNedre,ParkblekenSkaneglantan,BjornsTradgard,Aspuddsparken,Solvikangens,Vattersdalden];
      overlay[2] = [Sparvagnsparken,Drakenbergsparken,Junotappan,IvarLos,Ralis,Humlegarden,ParkblekenSkaneglantan,Vattersdalden];
      overlay[3] = [Humlegarden,BjornsTradgard];
      overlay[4] = [Observatorielundens,Kronobergsparken,Drakenbergsparken,Vasaparken,Ralis,Vangavan,Humlegarden,StoraBlecktornsparken,ParkblekenSkaneglantan,BjornsTradgard,Aspuddsparken,Vattersdalden];
      overlay[5] = [Sparvagnsparken,IvarLos,Luxparken,Signalparken,Vangavan,Bryggartappan,VanadislundensOvre,VanadislundensNedre,Solvikangens];
      overlay[6] = [Uggleparken,Observatorielundens,Kronobergsparken,Drakenbergsparken,Junotappan,AndersFranzens,Kristinebergs,KungsholmsStrand,Blomsterdalen,Sannadalsparken,LillaBatparken,Humlegarden,Timmermansparken,ParkblekenSkaneglantan,BjornsTradgard,TranebergsFritidspark,Aspuddsparken,Vattersdalden];
      overlay[7] = [StoraBlecktornsparken,Aspuddsparken];
      overlay[8] = [Fredhallsparkens,Drakenbergsparken,Engelskaparkens,Luxparken,Ralis,Sannadalsparken,Vangavan,TranebergsFritidspark,Aspuddsparken];
      overlay[9] = [Uggleparken,Observatorielundens,Kronobergsparken,Drakenbergsparken,AndersFranzens,Vasaparken,IvarLos,Luxparken,Ralis,Humlegarden,ParkblekenSkaneglantan,TranebergsFritidspark,Aspuddsparken,Vattersdalden];


    var dummy = [];    
      dummy[0] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 0, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[1] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 1, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[2] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 2, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[3] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 3, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[4] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 4, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[5] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 5, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[6] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 6, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[7] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 7, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[8] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 8, stroke: false, interactive: false});
      dummy[9] = L.polyline([[0, 0], [0, 0]], {myId: 9, stroke: false, interactive: false});

  var overlayMaps = {
       "All Playgrounds": dummy[0],
       "Restroom": dummy[1],
       "Public grills": dummy[2],
       "Accessible equipment": dummy[3],
       "Indoor area": dummy[4],
       "Fully fenced": dummy[5],
       "Partially fenced": dummy[6],
       "Animals": dummy[7],
       "Water play": dummy[8],
       "Toddler Area": dummy[9]
  };

  var markers = L.layerGroup([]).addTo(map);

map.on('overlayadd', function(evt) {
  var i = overlayMaps[evt.name].options.myId;
  for (var j = 0; j < overlay[i].length; j++) {
    if (markers.hasLayer(overlay[i][j])) {
      overlay[i][j].myCount += 1;
      }
    else {  
      overlay[i][j].myCount = 1;
      overlay[i][j].addTo(markers);
    }
  }
});

map.on('overlayremove', function(evt) {
  var i = overlayMaps[evt.name].options.myId;
  for (var j = 0; j < overlay[i].length; j++) {
    if (markers.hasLayer(overlay[i][j])) {
      overlay[i][j].myCount -= 1;
      if (overlay[i][j].myCount == 0) {
        markers.removeLayer(overlay[i][j]);
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

I have been playing around with restructuring the data but I am not skilled enough to make this version work:

```
<div id="mapid"></div>

<style>#mapid {
        height:100%;    
        width:100%;
        }
</style>


    <script>

var ColorIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    iconAnchor: [22.5, 45],
    popupAnchor: [5, -30]
  }
});



var blueIcon = new ColorIcon({
    iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6235-3462-4436-a462-636533303161/PINBLUE.png'
  }),
  redIcon = new ColorIcon({
    iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3338-6635-4361-b964-366333643732/PINRED.png'
  }),
  greenIcon = new ColorIcon({
    iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6263-6236-4366-b934-646361386631/PINGREEN.png'
  }),
  yellowIcon = new ColorIcon({
    iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6530-6637-4866-b564-373036303930/PINYELLOW.png'
  }),
  brownIcon = new ColorIcon({
    iconUrl: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3239-6138-4435-a331-636535323762/PINBROWN.png'
  });



const parks = [
    ['Spårvagnsparken', 59.3298868, 18.0031605, 'http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken', greenIcon, 'wc', 'grill', 'fence'],
    ['Fredhällsparkens plaskdamm', 59.3320485, 18.0029481, 'http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm', greenIcon, 'wc', 'water'],
    ['Uggleparken', 59.3343715, 18.0040208, 'http://leksply.com/uggleparken', greenIcon, 'wc', 'pfence' ],
    ['Observatorielundens Parklek', 59.3413877, 18.056007, 'http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek', greenIcon, 'wc', 'pfence', 'toddler'],
    ['Parklek Kronobergsparken', 59.331715, 18.0335563, 'http://leksplay.com/parklekkronobergsparken', greenIcon, 'wc', 'indoor', 'pfence', 'toddler'],
    ['Drakenbergsparken', 59.314187, 18.038608, 'http://leksplay.com/drakenbergsparken', greenIcon, 'wc', 'grill', 'indoor', 'pfence', 'toddler'],
    ['Fruktlekparken', 59.3109872, 18.0221863, 'http://leksplay.com/fruktlekparken', greenIcon],
    ['Junotäppan', 59.3235004, 18.0720134, 'http://leksplay.com/junotappan', greenIcon],
    ['Anders Franzens Park', 59.311421, 18.104492, 'http://leksplay.com/andersfranzenspark', greenIcon],
    ['Kristinebergs Ekparken', 59.334675, 18.0063813, 'http://leksplay.com/kristinebergsekparken', greenIcon],
    ['Engelskaparkens Plaskdamm', 59.3377166, 18.0012396, 'http://leksplay.com/engelskaparkensplaskdamm', greenIcon],
    ['Vasaparken Lekpark', 59.3399655, 18.0419433, 'http://leksplay.com/vasaparkenlekpark', greenIcon],
    ['Lekplatsen Kungsholms Strand', 59.3358832, 18.0406834, 'http://leksplay.com/lekplatsenkungsholmsstrand', greenIcon],
    ['Ivar Los Park', 59.3204862, 18.060975, 'http://leksplay.com/ivarlospark', greenIcon],
    ['Luxparken', 59.324224, 18.0092568, 'http://leksplay.com/luxparken', greenIcon],
    ['Rålis Parklek', 59.3283625, 18.0238191, 'http://leksplay.com/ralisparklek', greenIcon],
    ['Sannadalsparken', 59.3153587, 18.0091349, 'http://leksplay.com/sannadalsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Signalparken', 59.3277189, 18.0140405, 'http://leksplay.com/signalparken', greenIcon],
    ['Lilla båtparken', 59.3191497, 17.9831104, 'http://leksplay.com/lillabatparken', greenIcon],
    ['Vängåvan', 59.3219577, 17.9926997, 'http://leksplay.com/vangavan', greenIcon],
    ['Lurparken', 59.3011142, 17.9939973, 'http://leksplay.com/lurparken', greenIcon],
    ['Humlegården parklek', 59.3406553, 18.0728746, 'http://leksplay.com/humlegardenparklek', greenIcon],
    ['Stora Blecktornsparken', 59.3069209, 18.0866587, 'http://leksplay.com/storablecktornsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Bryggartäppan', 59.3102588, 18.0797964, 'http://leksplay.com/bryggartppan', greenIcon],
    ['Vanadislundens övre Lekplats', 59.3493288, 18.0541187, 'http://leksplay.com/vanadislundensovrelekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Vanadislundens nedre Lekplats', 59.3472582, 18.0534746, 'http://leksplay.com/vanadislundensnedrelekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Ellen Keys Lekplats', 59.3440353, 18.0641552, 'http://leksplay.com/ellenkeyslekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Timmermansparken', 59.3130356, 18.0624603, 'http://leksplay.com/timmermansparken', greenIcon],
    ['Parkleken Skånegläntan', 59.3112462, 18.0702012, 'http://leksplay.com/parklekenskaneglantan', greenIcon],
    ['Björns Trädgård', 59.31533, 18.0740494, 'http://leksplay.com/bjornstradgard', greenIcon],
    ['Trollparken', 59.3003486, 18.0618205, 'http://leksplay.com/trollparken', greenIcon],
    ['Aspuddsparken', 59.3075995, 17.9944431, 'http://leksplay.com/aspuddsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Solvikangens Lekplats', 59.3166851, 17.9613786, 'http://leksplay.com/solvikangenslekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Vättersdälden', 59.2964647, 18.0595962, 'http://leksplay.com/vattersdalden', greenIcon],
    ['Årstabergsparken', 59.3049504, 18.0254684, 'http://leksplay.com/arstabergsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Äventyrsparken i Årstabergsparken', 59.304634, 18.035536, 'http://leksplay.com/aventyrsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Årstabergsparken (Rävskogen)', 59.3049504, 18.0254684, 'http://leksplay.com/ravskogen', greenIcon],
    ['Årstabergsparken (Kråkberget)', 59.3049504, 18.0254684, 'http://leksplay.com/krakberget', greenIcon],
    ['Årstabergsparken (Sjövikskröken)', 59.3049504, 18.0254684, 'http://leksplay.com/sjovikskroken', greenIcon],
    ['Pontonjärparken', 59.3294826, 18.0326171, 'http://leksplay.com/pontonjarparken', greenIcon],
    ['Solvändan', 59.343872, 18.0337046, 'http://leksplay.com/solvandan', greenIcon],
    ['Sockerskålen Lekpark', 59.3092041, 18.0485767, 'http://leksplay.com/sockerskalenlekpark', greenIcon],
    ['Högalid park', 59.3177309, 18.0346969, 'http://leksplay.com/hogalidpark', greenIcon],
    ['Lekplats Bränneriet', 59.3175092, 18.0171891, 'http://leksplay.com/lekplatsbranneriet', greenIcon],
    ['Vitabergsparkens Lekplats', 59.3106141, 18.0899151, 'http://leksplay.com/vitabergsparkenslekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Gustaf Adolfs Parklek', 59.3370523, 18.099829, 'http://leksplay.com/gustafadolfsparklek', greenIcon],
    ['Honungslekplatsen', 59.3454831, 18.0924717, 'http://leksplay.com/honungslekplatsen', greenIcon],
    ['LekparkLinnégatan', 59.3355772, 18.0876746, 'http://leksplay.com/lekparklinnegatan', greenIcon],
    ['Parklek Tessinparken', 59.3446778, 18.0953018, 'http://leksplay.com/parklektessinparken', greenIcon],
    ['Lekplatsen Kungsholms Hamnplan', 59.3275547, 18.0462389, 'http://leksplay.com/lekplatsenkungsholmshamnplan', greenIcon],
    ['ReimersholmskajenLekpark', 59.3170307, 18.023085, 'http://leksplay.com/reimersholmskajenlekpark', greenIcon],
    ['Tranebergs Lekplats', 59.3320286, 17.9859598, 'http://leksplay.com/tranebergslekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Lekplatsen Skorstenen', 59.332832, 17.9745959, 'http://leksplay.com/lekplatsenskorstenen', greenIcon],
    ['Dragontorpet', 59.3335116, 17.948239, 'http://leksplay.com/dragontorpet', greenIcon],
    ['Galonparken', 59.3403444, 17.9469753, 'http://leksplay.com/galonparken', greenIcon],
    ['Pampasparken', 59.3506752, 18.0018109, 'http://leksplay.com/pampasparken', greenIcon],
    ['Bergsparken', 59.3532442, 17.9984016, 'http://leksplay.com/bergsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Byparkens Parklek', 59.3523879, 17.9843705, 'http://leksplay.com/byparkensparklek', greenIcon],
    ['Lekplats Nybodagatan', 59.3561097, 17.9904962, 'http://leksplay.com/lekplatsnybodagatan', greenIcon],
    ['Skytteholmsparken', 59.3588091, 17.9929853, 'http://leksplay.com/skytteholmsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Blomparken', 59.2985792, 18.0376414, 'http://leksplay.com/blomparken', greenIcon],
    ['Grynkvarnsparken', 59.2973854, 18.0735247, 'http://leksplay.com/grynkvarnsparken', greenIcon],
    ['Motalaparken', 59.3533937, 18.0941425, 'http://leksplay.com/motalaparken', greenIcon],
    ['Dianaparkens Parklek', 59.3563711, 18.1012935, 'http://leksplay.com/dianaparkensparklek', greenIcon],
    ['Ekorrparken Lekplats', 59.3559171, 18.0854114, 'http://leksplay.com/Ekorrparken Lekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Lekplatsen Hälsingehöjden', 59.3440376, 18.0406971, 'http://leksplay.com/lekplatsenhalsingehojden', greenIcon],
    ['Sickla Park', 59.3048158, 18.108975, 'http://leksplay.com/sicklapark', greenIcon],
    ['Lilla Kvarnholmen Lekplats', 59.3153088, 18.1378446, 'http://leksplay.com/lillakvarnholmenlekplats', greenIcon],
    ['Kvarnholmens Lekplats', 59.3174047, 18.1435966, 'http://leksplay.com/kvarnholmenslekplats', greenIcon]
    ];

    const categories = ['wc', 'grill', 'access', 'indoor', 'fence', 'pfence', 'animals', 'water', 'toddler'];
    const markers = Object.fromEntries(
      categories.map(cat => [cat, []])
    );

    const makeMarker = park => L.marker([park[1], park[2]], {
        icon: park[4]
      })
      .bindPopup("<a href='" + park[3] + "'>" + park[0] + "</a>");
    for (const park of parks) {
      const marker = makeMarker(park);
      const cat = categories.find(cat => park[7].includes(cat));
      markers[cat].push(marker);
    }




var main = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1,
                zoomControl: false,
                accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWljaGFlbGNwIiwiYSI6ImNrN3V5eHVwNTAxMzgza2x1d2s1N3lkbmIifQ.Rmgw9tQHXVTL5_w6jvGjlw'
        });
    var baseMaps = {
        'OSM': main
    };
    var map = L.map('mapid', {
                 center: [59.3244941,18.028934],
                 zoom: 12,
                 layers: [main]
        });




</script>
```

Comment: Please don't put the whole question in the title. You'll have to describe a bit more what you (or the code) is doing and is now working as expected and what you want to achieve, but don't know how to.

Comment: While not technically a "Wall of code" post, there is a far too high *code to problem statement* ratio as currently written. The purpose of including code is so that the problem description can be understood. The title exists to describe the problem subject, and really ought to be generated last, after the Question is fully written and formatted. The code provided in a question should be a minimal subset to describe the issue and which still exhibits the problem. Please [Edit] your Question to include a problem statement and describe how your attempted solution doesn't meet the goal.

Comment: @vince thanks for the feedback, edited

Comment: You still aren't describing what isn't working.

Comment: @vince how about now?

Comment: No, too vague. GIS SE isn't a coding service, it's a problem-solving site. You've described a goal, but not the problem. What is it about the attempted solution that doesn't work? What does it do instead? What diagnostics have you added to understand the problem? What output do you get in the log? The only place "union" exists is in the title. If that's the issue, it should be more prevalent in the description.

Comment: Alright then, I'm not sure how to formulate it. The issue is simply that I don't know how to approach my goal at all. Someone else helped me get this far and just don't know enough about JavaScript or how the leaflet control can be modified to do a Boolean lookup and create markers on checkbox toggle. @vince

Comment: You wrote "so that my map only displays the logical union between layer groups". That's how it is now (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)). You probably mean intersection (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)).

Comment: @TomazicM  yes, that is what I meant. I am going to just scrap this and write a new question.

Comment: @TomazicM I revised this, if you are still interested in helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code custom marker property `myCount` is used to count how many marker groups which are selected to be displayed have this marker as a member. If `myCount` is greater than 1, marker is added to the map. This means that all the markers of all selected groups are displayed, which is union of the marker groups.

To have only intersection of the selected marker groups displayed, condition has to be changed: marker should be displayed only if it's included in all of the selected groups, which effectively means that `myCount` property of the displayed marker has to be equal to the number of selected groups.

This complicates the code a bit. I won't explain it in detail, code speaks for itself:

```
var selectedOverlays = [];

map.on('overlayadd', function(evt) {
  var marker;
  var i = overlayMaps[evt.name].options.myId;
  selectedOverlays.push(i);
  var nOverlays = selectedOverlays.length;
  for (var j = 0; j < overlay[i].length; j++) {
    marker = overlay[i][j];
    if (typeof marker.myCount == 'undefined') {
      marker.myCount = 1;
      }
    else {
      marker.myCount += 1;
    }
    if ((marker.myCount == nOverlays) && !markers.hasLayer(marker)) {
      marker.addTo(markers);
    }
  }
  markers.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    if (marker.myCount < nOverlays) {
      markers.removeLayer(marker);
    }
  });
});

map.on('overlayremove', function(evt) {
  var marker;
  var i = overlayMaps[evt.name].options.myId;
  var j = selectedOverlays.indexOf(i);
  selectedOverlays.splice(j, 1);
  var nOverlays = selectedOverlays.length;
  for (var j = 0; j < overlay[i].length; j++) {
    marker = overlay[i][j];
    marker.myCount -= 1;
    if (markers.hasLayer(marker)) {
      if ((marker.myCount < nOverlays) || (marker.myCount == 0)) {
        markers.removeLayer(marker);
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < selectedOverlays.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < overlay[i].length; j++) {
      marker = overlay[i][j];
      if (marker.myCount == nOverlays) {
        if (!markers.hasLayer(marker)) {
          marker.addTo(markers);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am learning a lot and hope to continue. I am a newbie to the community and hope to give back like you one day. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelPerna The best way to give thanks is to up-vote the answer. See the [Help Center page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Vince not enough rep