# Finding the intersection of an array of markers across multiple layer groups Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap

I have two challenges related to this. The first(1) is that I have created a bunch of variables that store the data needed for my markers and I cannot reliably add markers to layer groups when storing it this way. I can't figure out why. It is an array called 'parks'.

I wrote them out like previously but cannot use it this way any longer because I have hundreds of them:

```
var Lurparken = L.marker([59.3011142,17.9939973], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/lurparken'>Lurparken</a>"),
    Aspuddsparken    = L.marker([59.3075995,17.9944431], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/aspuddsparken'>Aspuddsparken</a>"),
    Sparvagnsparken    = L.marker([59.3298868,18.0031605], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken'>Spårvagnsparken</a>"),
    Fredhallsparkens    = L.marker([59.3320485,18.0029481], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm'>Fredhällsparkens Plaskdamm</a>"),
    Uggleparken    = L.marker([59.3343715,18.0040208], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksply.com/uggleparken'>Uggleparken</a>"),
    Observatorielundens    = L.marker([59.3413877,18.056007], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek'>Observatorielundens Parklek</a>"),
    Kronobergsparken    = L.marker([59.331715,18.0335563], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/parklekkronobergsparken'>Parklek Kronobergsparken</a>"),
    Drakenbergsparken    = L.marker([59.314187,18.038608], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup("<a href='http://leksplay.com/drakenbergsparken'>Drakenbergsparken</a>");
```

Instead I want to store them like this where the array after 'greenIcon' is a set of attributes. You can see they vary by each marker, sometimes there are 2 or 3 attributes but there can be up to 10 in my set of data. Example:

```
const parks = [
    ['Spårvagnsparken', 59.3298868, 18.0031605, 'http://leksplay.com/sparvagnsparken', greenIcon, ['wc', 'grill', 'fence']],
    ['Fredhällsparkens plaskdamm', 59.3320485, 18.0029481, 'http://leksplay.com/fredhallsparkensplaskdamm', greenIcon, ['wc', 'water']],
    ['Uggleparken', 59.3343715, 18.0040208, 'http://leksply.com/uggleparken', greenIcon, ['wc', 'pfence',]],
    ['Observatorielundens Parklek', 59.3413877, 18.056007, 'http://leksplay.com/observatorielundensparklek', greenIcon, ['wc', 'pfence', 'toddler']],
    ['Parklek Kronobergsparken', 59.331715, 18.0335563, 'http://leksplay.com/parklekkronobergsparken', greenIcon, ['wc', 'indoor', 'pfence', 'toddler']],
    ['Drakenbergsparken', 59.314187, 18.038608, 'http://leksplay.com/drakenbergsparken', greenIcon, ['wc', 'grill', 'indoor', 'pfence', 'toddler']]
];
```

Now the journey begins. I have managed (structuring the data in the first way above) to manually place each marker inside a layer group so that the standard Leaflet controller can display or remove. I also managed to use dummy groups in order to prevent the map from removing markers that belong to two groups when one of  the active groups is removed. There is a [working example](https://leksplay.com/test-or) of this here (excuse my invalid SSL cert, launching a site is complicated).

I am new to JavaScript. I am looking for a way to (1) create markers from my data (array 'parks'), toggle those markers on with leaflet's regular controller i.e.:

```
var overlayMaps = {
       "string": obj
  };
```

Then (2) display the intersection of attributes (i.e. 'wc', 'fence', 'grill') on the map when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: If you ask me, previous one (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363320/is-there-a-way-to-reform-this-so-that-i-get-the-union-of-checked-layer-groups) was much better than this one, since relevant code was included. You would just need to replace word "union" with "intersection".

Comment: @TomazicM I revised the other one. Also, thank you for your help before. I am learning a lot partly from your code!